# Pass fastify request schema to NestJS controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, backend, fastify

I am trying to use fastify+NestJS. However, in order to use, in my opinion, the main strength of fastify, its speed, I need to get profit of fastify json schema. However, I do not understand how can I inject such a schema in a NestJS controller. Can you help me please?

Comment: AFIK, NestjJS doesn't have a nice wrapper around this great feat of Fastify. You'll need see if we can supply those validation schemas without having the request handler (because nestjs didn't expose them).

Comment: also, you can request this feature on https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues I didn't saw any issues on this topic yet

Comment: there's one about it but it wasn't using that schema feature from fastify https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4149

Comment: @MicaelLevi thank you for your answer! As far as I have investigated, there is indeed nothing ready out of the box with nest js. I came to the conclusion that I do not even need to use this feature of fastify. The speedup it gives is being bottlenecked by a time needed to communicate with a database server. While swagger documentation can be generated using class-validator + nest-js-swagger combination.

Comment: is there any libraries or ways to connect fastify validation into nest? in 2023)